# Serializing/Deserializing Bitmap causes the image to change

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, bitmap, deserialization

I have code that serializes/deserializes bitmap objects. For some image files (especially png files) I found out that the size of the file is reduced after deserializing it, and the image quality is reduced. And if I serialize the deserialized image again, the resulting byte array is different compared to what it was before. Has anyone experienced the same problem? If so, how were you able to solve it?

Here is my code snippet:

```
    private byte[] GetBytes(Bitmap image)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(ms, image);
            byte[] _bytes = ms.ToArray();
            return _bytes;
        }
    }

    private Bitmap GetImage(byte[] _bytes)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(_bytes))
        {
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
            return bmp;
        }
    }
```

**PS:** Using an **Image** object instead of **Bitmap** seems to solve the problem, but I'd rather not change the object type due to external dependencies.